# Firestore adding to map without deleting

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to add to a map field but when i try this line it replaces the current fields under the map. How can I add new elements to a map without replacing the current values?

```
var document = await db.collection("trips").document(widget.tripInfo.documentID).updateData({
                'members': {
                  name : id,
                },
              });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update a nested field, use dot notation:

```
db.collection("trips").document(widget.tripInfo.documentID)
  .updateData({ 'members.name': id })
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating fields on a nested object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Comment: Thank you so much!!